# iPad app Crashes after syncing from iTunes

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes, synchronization

Hi my application is crashes after syncint it from iTunes. When I touch the app icon to open the application after compliting the syncing process the app is going to be crashes.I can see app icon on iPad but it is also blank.I dono why it happens?
Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The application that crashes, was it installed using a different Apple ID? You may have to re-install the app using the same Apple ID that is used to sync the iPad with iTunes.

Comment: Thanks Aziz, but what if I prepare ipa file then also is it necessary?

Comment: I have seem the same issue on my devices. Not sure about it exact cause. Had to reinstall certain apps.